# Knockout Mapping - rebind data after JSON loads

Tags: mapping, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout with mapping plugin.
I have got problem with initializing page BEFORE server return JSON data.

Everything works fine in scenario:
1. get JSON
2. perform `VM = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);`
3. perform `ko.applyBinding(VM);`

however if JSON takes some time to return (e.g. 10 seconds) my page needs to be initialized before json is returned. But if I make `ko.applyBinding(VM);` with empty VM (`let say VM = {};`) than call for JSON, and then rebind it again - it won't work.

So my question is - how to rebind model with knockout? I don't want to change value of single observable, but to rebind entire VM (view model) because structure of my data needs to be mapped from JSON - and it is not known before JSON is returned.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem you are describing is that things will not render (and will actually give an error) in your template immediately, and that error prevents the redraw when the data from the server arrives.

If that is the case, the way I generally handle this is to have an observable that *knows* when the data has been loaded, and the wrap the problematic template code in an `if` based on this observable.

Update: it is more likely that you are replacing the value of VM. This is no longer the object that is bound to the interface elements.

You can just use the alternate form of the `ko.mapping.fromJS` call.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, VM);
```

Comment: no, there is no JS error.

everything is fine. the problem is that the initial empty binded VM will bind and page is empty (which is OK), but when I want to rebind VM (with complex structure of nested arrays) it will not rebind (re-render).

in other words - if I bind something simple (empty) once, it can't be rebinded with more complex structure.

Comment: the alternate version doesn't work either. I mean it works if 1st bind was with empty element, but containing structure... I mean if I bind complex array structure (with nested arrays etc.) but all of them are empty, and then bind correct data from JSON (with the same data structre) than it works... however I want to bind it with empty element first... and then with data from JSON.